# AngularJs:How to create a tooltip in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

We are trying to determine what tooltip plugin we should use for web page that uses AngularUI to get an effect like this (or close to this)

[image: Tooltip Image]

Answer (score 0):

the angular-ui popover plugin with some custom html and css would do the job:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap

Comment: @MajoB-sir,we want to create a tooltip without bootstrap

Comment: @Sindhu the angular ui bootstrap components are completely rewritten in angularjs they are using just bootstrap css (which you  can download only for the popover http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)